# API key strange behaviour

Tags: ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

We have application in AppStore with Googla Maps iOS SDK. Everything worked fine but couple of days ago maps stopped loading and I can see these errors in logs:

```
2015-11-12 16:06:44.476 AppNAME[30186:18560579] Google Maps SDK for iOS version: 1.10.20339.0
2015-11-12 16:06:44.476 AppNAME[30186:18560579] New version of Google Maps SDK for iOS available: 1.10.21020.0
2015-11-12 16:06:44.485 AppNAME[30186:18560579] ClientParametersRequest failed, 3 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<CFData 0x7c149760 [0x4dcc098]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
2015-11-12 16:06:44.683 AppNAME[30186:18560579] ClientParametersRequest failed, 2 attempts remaining (0 vs 6). Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=400 "(null)" UserInfo={data=<CFData 0x7c60ecf0 [0x4dcc098]>{length = 145, capacity = 256, bytes = 0x3c48544d4c3e0a3c484541443e0a3c54 ... 3c2f48544d4c3e0a}}
```

I can fix it with new key, but I have to redeploy app. Is there any way to make it working again?

Comment: And you've enabled everything on the google end?

Comment: I also faced the same problem but I am unable to remove that massage but I fixed the map by just using the old GoogleMap.framework instead of GoogleMapM4B.framework